# How can I rename bookmarks in evince?

Tags: pdf, evince

When adding a bookmark in evince it simply adds the page number. How can one rename the bookmarks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>F9</kbd>, go to `Bookmarks` in the side menu on the left, click on the bookmark name or right press and choose `Rename Bookmark`. Also described  [here](https://help.gnome.org/users/evince/stable/bookmarks.html.en).

Comment: On the side menu on the left, you have to first switch from Index to Bookmarks on a dropdown on the top of the side bar. Tested on Ubuntu 16.04, Evince 3.18.4.